# Get rid of Content-type in postman request

Tags: rest, postman

I have changed my app so that it sets `Content-type` to `application/json` in case if the header is absent and now trying to test it.

For this purpose I use Postman. However, when I uncheck "Content-type" header in "Headers" tab Postman still sends `Content-type=text/plain;charset=UTF-8`.

Is there a way to avoid this and just not send anything in `Content-type` header?

Would appreciate any help, thanks

Comment: What post method are you using?

Comment: @DanielElmnas POST

Comment: Can you post `nothing` in the body? Or does it need to be a certain payload? Failing that, do you *need* to use Postman for this? Maybe a basic cURL request would do it.

Comment: @DannyDainton No, I can't. To tell the truth, there is no reason of using Postman, but all others client failed - I tried to use curl and it also sets this header by default. Java default HttpClient sets this header by default too if no value is set

Answer (score 16):

Go to the body tab, select 'raw' from the sub menu. To the right of 'binary' in the sub menu, a picklist will be available. Select 'Text' (not 'Text[text/plain]') from this list. This will remove the Content-Type header. 
[image]

Comment: This is still sending `Content-Type: text/plain` according to netcat

Comment: I selected Json instead of Text and wrote some json in the body

Answer (score 0):

There are two worrying things here.

> so that it sets Content-type to application/json

Are you saying you want request bodies to be interpreted as JSON even if they do not specify it as JSON? WHY?! This can lead to all sorts of confusion, future frameworks could have weird defaults triggered, and failing to be specific now is going to bite in the future.

Are you maybe confusing Content-Type and Accept? I see that happen a lot.

Also another bit seemed odd:

> and now trying to test it.

Why are you testing "in the browser" like this? APIs are easily tested with integration tests, where you fire a few headers at your controller and see how it responds.

```
it 'is fine' do
  post '/endpoint', params: params, headers: { 'Content-Type' => 'foo' }

  expect(response).to match_some_whatever
end

it 'is also fine I guess' do
  post '/endpoint', params: params

  expect(response).to match_some_whatever
end
```

Tests do a better job of ensuring the thing works, otherwise you gotta check everything in Postman whenever you change stuff. That takes time, is unrealistic, and is going to lead to you pushing production issues regularly.